# Qt Uso del método contains() no da los resultados esperados

Tags: c++, qt

Quiero hacer un pequeño programa que instale de forma automática una extensión en PostgreSQL, y que funcione tanto en Windows como en Linux.

Para ello, la estrategia que se me ha ocurrido (y debido a que el directorio por defecto de instalación de PostgreSQL puede ser cualquiera, y más en Linux), es buscar la extensión `plpgsql`, que se instala siempre. De esta forma podré hallar la ruta donde se alojan las extensiones.

Para ello parto de ésto:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDirIterator>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QDirIterator it("/usr", QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    //QRegExp rx("sql$");
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        if (it.next().contains("plpgsql--1.0.sql"))
        {
            qDebug() << it.next();
        }
    }
    qDebug()<<"Fin";

    return a.exec();
}
```

Estoy haciendo uso del método :

```
bool QString::contains(const QString &str, Qt::CaseSensitivity cs = Qt::CaseSensitive) const
```

Pues bien, el resultado que me da es:

```
"/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/btree_gin--1.0.sql"
Fin
```

Cuando realmente existe el fichero buscado. `plpgsql--1.0.sql` en ese mismo directorio.

¿Alguien sabe interpretar este resultado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentación del método `next`:

> QString QDirIterator::next()
>
> Advances the iterator to the next entry, and returns the file path of this new entry. If hasNext() returns false, this function does nothing, and returns an empty QString.

Que viene a decir algo así como que cada llamada a `next` **avanza el iterador**.

Pues bien, fíjate que tu estás llamando dos veces a `next`:

```
    if (it.next().contains("plpgsql--1.0.sql")) // <<--- 1
    {
        qDebug() << it.next();                  // <<--- 2
    }
```

Es decir, `contains` funciona correctamente, lo que sucede es que la salida de `qDebug` te está mostrando el siguiente fichero.

Lo que tienes que hacer es guardar el nombre del fichero en una variable para evitar llamadas recurrentes a `next()`

```
QString file = it.next();
if( file.contains("plpgsql--1.0.sql"))
{
  qDebug() << file;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, como siempre!. Al no caer en el error verdadero, estaba intentando centrarme en el comportamiento de la propia función, al que no le veía un resultado lógico. Ahora me tengo que centrar en la expresión regular que satisfaga cualquier versión de plpgsql, pero si no lo consigo ya haré otra pregunta :)